# Save m2m in FormView django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, manytomanyfield

I'm trying to save a m2m field in a `FormView`.

Here is my code:

```
class ProductorPropietarioView(FormView):
    form_class = FormPropietario
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'productores/propietario.html'

    def form_valid(self,form):      
        form.save(commit=False)
        form.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return super(ProductorPropietarioView,self).form_valid(form)
```

models.py

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    predio = models.ForeignKey(InfoPredioGeneral,related_name='predio+')
    rol = models.ManyToManyField(RolPersona)
    tipo_identificacion = models.ForeignKey(TipoIdentificacion,related_name='tipo identificacion+',blank=True,null=True)
    numero_identificacion = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class FormPropietario(ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Persona
        fields = '__all__'
```

I can't get this to work. I know that first I have to set False then save the form and then save the m2m. I already tried only with `form.save()`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a `ModelForm`? Also, It is not required to do `form.save(commit=False)`. You can just call `form.save()` then all data including the many-to-many data to be save.

Comment: @RodXavier Yes, its a ModelForm, I tried already only with form.save() but does not save

 `def form_valid(self,form):  
  form.save()
  return super(ProductorPropietarioView,self).form_valid(form)`

Comment: Can you post you form and the models concerned here?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your `FormView` as follows:

```
    def form_valid(self,form):      
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return super(ProductorPropietarioView,self).form_valid(form)
```